# How do i add website icons and Website name to EasyTabs

Tags: c#, tabs, visual-studio-2019, cefsharp

So... I'm creating a web browser in visual studio 2019 and I have all the things a browser should have Tabs Setting enter to search functionality and more. the only thing that's missing is is when I want to see the website Name & Image in an EasyTabs Tab. I was wanting to replace the app icon image in easy tabs with the website I'm on in that tab, and I also was wanting to replace the name of the EasyTab instead of it saying new tab I want it to specify a website that I'm currently at like bing for example. can someone please help me with this? it would be greatly appreciated. for more information heres my AppContainer Code

```
namespace Damonic
{
   public partial class AppContainer : TitleBarTabs
   {
       public AppContainer()
       {   
           InitializeComponent();

           AeroPeekEnabled = true;
           TabRenderer = new ChromeTabRenderer(this);
       }

    // Handle the method CreateTab that allows the user to create a new Tab
    // on your app when clicking
    public override TitleBarTab CreateTab()
    {
        return new TitleBarTab(this)
        {
            // The content will be an instance of another Form
            // In our example, we will create a new instance of the Form1
            Content = new Form1
            {
                Text = "New Tab"
            }
        };
    }

    // The rest of the events in your app here if you need to .....
}
```

}

Here is my Form1.cs Code

```
namespace Damonic
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       // 2. Important: Declare ParentTabs
       protected TitleBarTabs ParentTabs
       {
           get
           {
               return (ParentForm as TitleBarTabs);
           }
       }

       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

    ChromiumWebBrowser Browser;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        //Initialize
        CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true; // Enable Register JS Object, -- RegisterAsyncJsObject, RegisterJsObject allow
        settings.CachePath = "cache";
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "1"); //Enable WebRTC4
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1");
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-compositing", "1");

        BrowserSettings browserSettings = new BrowserSettings
        {
            FileAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled,
            UniversalAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled,
            WebSecurity = CefState.Enabled
        };

        Browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(AddressText.Text);
        this.pContainer.Controls.Add(Browser);
        Browser.DownloadHandler = new DownloadHandler();
        Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Browser.Load("https://example.com/home/search?/enginecodec34958439543954989358?.;okoDS|pageloaded");
        this.AcceptButton = this.NavigateToURL;
        Browser.AddressChanged += Browser_AddressChanged;
        Browser.TitleChanged += Browser_TitleChanged;
    }

    private void Browser_TitleChanged(object sender, TitleChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            EasyTabs.SelectedTab.Text = e.Title;
        }));
    }

    private void Browser_AddressChanged(object sender, AddressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            AddressText.Text = e.Address;
        }));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Browser.CanGoBack)
            Browser.Back();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Browser.CanGoForward)
            Browser.Forward();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Browser.Reload();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Browser.Load("https://example.com/home/search?/enginecodec34958439543954989358?.;okoDS|pageloaded");
    }

    private void SecuritySettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void AddressBar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddressText.Clear();
    }

    private void NavigateToURL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Browser.Load(AddressText.Text);
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Browser.Load("https://login.live.com/");
    }
}
```

}
iv entered everything people told me to enter and iv even looked in the EasyTabs Master Project and I don't understand it and cefsharp example is not even in it
can someone at lease give me the code to enter, I already have a title event but it doesn't work, it has no errors but just doesn't work. Please Help. if you want to see what I'm talking about i will import an image [Here](https://cleverdamontoutube.wixsite.com/video) that shows the text ("New Tab") i want the name of that to change based on what website im on.
F

Comment: You can use http://cefsharp.github.io/api/81.3.x/html/E_CefSharp_WinForms_ChromiumWebBrowser_TitleChanged.htm to get the title change notification. If by icon you are referring to `Favicon` then you need to implement http://cefsharp.github.io/api/81.3.x/html/T_CefSharp_IDisplayHandler.htm and assign to http://cefsharp.github.io/api/81.3.x/html/P_CefSharp_WinForms_ChromiumWebBrowser_DisplayHandler.htm The http://cefsharp.github.io/api/81.3.x/html/M_CefSharp_IDisplayHandler_OnFaviconUrlChange.htm method will be called with a list of urls currently available, download and display one.

Comment: im talking aboutm you know how on google chrome when you look at the top at one of your tabs you have open do you see what the website name is and what its icon looks like. thanks for the favcon code tho i will use it to

Comment: That's the title which you used the event I linked.

Comment: does the Title Event Work with EasyTabs

Comment: I cannot answer easy tabs questions as I've never used it. It's a standard event so it's quite likely.

Comment: ok thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your Browser_TitleChange just remove the "EasyTabs.SelectedTab" you
just need "Text = e. Title"

And to add the the favicon in the easytabs title bar create a function. Then call that function in the Browser_TitleChange

```
public void favicon(){
Uri url = new Uri("https://"+ new Uri(browser.Address).Host+ "/favicon.ico";
 try{
 Icon img = new Icon(new System.IO.MemoryStream(new 
 WebClient().DownloadData(url)));
 this. Icon = img; 
 }catch (Exception) {
 this.Icon =  Properties.Resources.tempIcon;
 //change tempIcon to your desired icon, extension is .ico 
 }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you this works, but it for some reason loads knda slow when registoring the favecon

Comment: nevermined i fixed it, thank you for the response

Answer (score 1):

```
private void chromiumWebBrowser1_AddressChanged(object sender, AddressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = e.Address));
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(e.Address);
        {
            try
            {
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();

                MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData("https://" + uri.Host + "/favicon.ico"));
                Icon icon = new Icon(memorystream);  
                {               

                    memorystream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        Icon = new Icon(memorystream);

                        ParentTabs.UpdateThumbnailPreviewIcon(ParentTabs.Tabs.Single(t => t.Content == this));
                        ParentTabs.RedrawTabs();
                    }));
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Invoke(new Action(() => Icon = Resources.DefaultIcon));
            }
        }

        Invoke(new Action(() => Parent.Refresh()));
        faviconLoaded = true;
    }
}
```